# Symfony & Api-Platform: Issue on post and put with ManyToMany relation

Tags: orm, api-platform.com

I have 2 entities Foo & Bar with a ManyToMany relation :

```
    namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  normalizationContext={"groups"={"foo:read"}},
 *  denormalizationContext={"groups"={"foo:write"}},
 *   collectionOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_DEVROOT')"}
 *   },
 *   itemOperations={
 *      "get",
 *      "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_DEVROOT')"},
 *      "delete"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_DEVROOT')"},
 *   }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FooRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"label"}, message="There is already a PTUR with this label")
 */
//Direct access from API (No DTO)
class Foo
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"foo:read", "foo:write"})
     */
    private $id;
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bar", inversedBy="foos", cascade="all")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="footobar",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bar_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
     * )
     * @Groups({"foo:read", "foo:write"})
     */
    private $bars;

    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bars = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @return Collection|Bar[]
     * @Groups({"foo:read", "foo:write"})
     */
    public function getBars(): Collection
    {
        return $this->bars;
    }

    public function addBars(Bar $bars): self
    {
        if (!$this->bars->contains($bars)) {
            $this->bars[] = $bars;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBars(Bar $bars): self
    {
        if ($this->bars->contains($bars)) {
            $this->bars->removeElement($bars);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    ...

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->label;
    }

}




namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  normalizationContext={"groups"={"bar:read"}},
 *  denormalizationContext={"groups"={"bar:write"}},
 *   collectionOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "post"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_DEVROOT')"}
 *   },
 *   itemOperations={
 *      "get",
 *      "put"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_DEVROOT')"},
 *      "delete"={"security"="is_granted('ROLE_DEVROOT')"},
 *   }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BarRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"label"}, message="There is already a PTU with this label")
 */
//Direct access from API (No DTO)
class Bar
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"bar:read", "bar:write"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"bar:read", "bar:write"})
     */
    private $isdefault = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Foo", mappedBy="bars")
     * @Groups({"bar:read", "bar:write"})
     */
    private $foos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->label;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Foo[]
     * @Groups({"bar:read", "bar:write"})
     */
    public function getFoos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->foos;
    }

    public function addFoo(Foo $foo): self
    {
        if (!$this->foos->contains($foo)) {
            $this->foos[] = $foo;
            $foo->addBars($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFoo(Foo $foo): self
    {
        if ($this->foos->contains($foo)) {
            $this->foos->removeElement($foo);
            $foo->removeBars($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I make a POST or PUT request on Foo, the crosstable is not filled (checked with phpmyadmin) (JSON):

{"id":3,"label":"ccccc","bars":["/xxx/api/bars/1","/xxx/api/bars/3"],"enrangebase":true,"enabled":true,"isdefault":false}

What did I miss?
Is there a way to track the error?

Thank you for your help,

EDIT1: added normalization groups
EDIT2: added normalization groups to Bar

Comment: Check your serializer groups and allow relation to be Serialised/Deserialize depending on requirements. It does what you tell it to do.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there any possibility to go to chat please, I am lost with groups.

Comment: I then added
 normalizationContext={"groups"={"Read"}},
 denormalizationContext={"groups"={"Write"}},
in my Foo entity (the one on which I need to select elements of the second one)
aand added hte @groups to all field.

Comment: BUT it does not solve my problem....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bar", inversedBy="foos")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="footobar",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bar_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
     * )
     * @Groups({"Read", "Write"})
     */
    private $bars;

Comment: Can you edit your question with groups? It would be better for understanding which part is normalized with which group. When you are talking about relation, it uses normalization group for collection as relation itself is a collection. Individual group doesn't apply there.

Comment: please see my EDIT

Comment: Let's say you have "bar:read" on bar resource, now if you want to embed foo, each property on foo should contain "bar:read", so when serializer is serializing bar object, it will also serialize properties of foos marked with "bar:read". That is embedding resource. Same goes for any type of operation specific groups. You can have group called "foo:collection:read" or "bar:item:read" and serialize specific property of any related object at output. You can even specify groups at get,put,post,query level.

Comment: I understand the embeding resource : it permits for example when you GET foo, to embed in Json the linked bar entities, instead of having only their api request endpoint. This avoid having to perform sveral requests, right?
In my case, for the moment I am working on PUT & POST for Foo entity. I do not want to create nor update any Bar. they all exist and may not be modified. I just want to assoicate Foo with some existing Bars. In this case, I should put @groups on the crosstable fields, but it is not an entity. it is generated by doctrine....

Comment: That is exactly what you do for write operation too, you add write group to your relation. When you add write group documentation should also auto update what is expected at input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214726/discussion-between-alexglvr-and-maulik-parmar).

Comment: Hi, coming back to issue, can you explain why getFoo() and getBar() methods have groups? You need them on property only.

Comment: you can define groups for Entities, with the possibility to assign a group to 1 or several action, and also to fields. Once a group is defined (for example with the right to read $id and $label of Foo), you can also use it in Bar to read, for example it $id field. Then when you make a re'quest to read Foo, Iti will include in the answer all the associated Bar ids...
BUT, this does not solve the original PB. My goal was to associate Foo with existing Bars : no working ready to use solution apparently. I achived it with DTO on Foo and manual association.

Comment: That's because when you define group on property it's getter/setter is resolved automatically.  Now you have group on getter but not on setter method so it's overriding property serializer config ultimately to non existent addFoo or addBar method. So either add groups to add and remove method as well or simply use groups on property only, not on methods.